# Classic ASP site restricted

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running Classic ASP site on WinServer 2008 R2 machine with MSAccess database.
The site runs perfectly when I pass the browser a user that is admin on the server.
For any other user the site fails to run.
I singled out the line in the code that causes the problem:

```
    Set rsUser = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
// Response.Write("here") -> returns here
// Response.End()
    rsUser.ActiveConnection = Application("CnnUsers") 
// Response.Write("here2") -> doesn't get here
// Response.End()
```

Application Pool Settings:
.NET Framework version: .Net Framework V2.0... / No Managed Code - tried both.
Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated / Classic - tried both
Enable 32-bit applications: True
Identity: Network Service / ApplicationPoolIdentity - tried both
Load User Profile: True / False - tried both

Web Site IIS Settings:
Windows Authentication: Enabled
Every other Authentication: Disabled
Extended protection: Off
Enable Kernel-mode authentication: checked
Providers: Negotiate, NTLM - tried both orders
Enable Parent Paths: True
Code Page: 1252

Folder Security: Everyone, Network Service, IIS_USRS, IUSRS, Users, AppPool - Full Control

What am i missing here?
Thank You.

Comment: Where is your access database, and do the relevant folder permissions all apply to it?

Answer (score 1):

First step in troubleshooting would be to see where `Application("CnnUsers")` is being set. I'd like to hope it's in `global.asa`, but I've seen some sites...

Next step would be to check and make sure that there is an actual value assigned to `Application("CnnUsers")` (You can Response.Write it out). If there's an incorrect value, or if it's not getting set for some reason, we at least know where to start looking.

It would help to know what you mean by "fails to run"...

- Do you mean some function isn't working?
- Do you mean the whole site is just dead?
- Is there an error? If so, what is the whole error (error number and message returned)?

Comment: Application("CnnUsers") is set in global.asa and its value is correct.
The error is probably caused by rsUser.ActiveConnection. I'm guessing because rsUser is null.

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg - is there an actual error we can reference? it would help cut down on the guess-and-check...

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg you'll need to set the server to send detailed error messages, and if you're using IE you'll need to disable "Show friendly error messages"